# R clasification of a number

Tags: r

I am working in R, but I don't know very well how to extract from any number a series of data, i.e., from the number 20102168056, I want to subdivide it like this

- 2010 -> year
- 2 -> semester
- 168 -> university career
- 056 -> unique number

I tried to do it with an if, but every time I got more errors, I am new to this and I would like to know if you can help me (By the way, it is for any number, as 20211888070, so I did not use the if I raised).

Comment: Is that a number or a string? If a number, you can use `%/%` (integer division), `%%` modulus, or various arithmetic mechanisms to extract those components. If it is a string (or perhaps it's a number and you want to coerce to a string with `as.character`), then you can simply use `substr(x, 1, 4)` and such for each component.

Comment: `read.fwf(textConnection('20102168056'), widths = c(4, 1, 3, 3))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(original = c(20102168056, 20141152013, 20182008006))

df %>% 
    separate(original, into = c("year", "semester", "university_career", "unique_number"), sep = c(4,5,8,11))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  year  semester university_career unique_number
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>             <chr>        
1 2010  2        168               056          
2 2014  1        152               013          
3 2018  2        008               006
```

You may want to convert some of the columns to an integer:

```
df %>% 
    separate(original, into = c("year", "semester", "university_career", "unique_number"), sep = c(4,5,8,11)) %>% 
    mutate(across(year:unique_number, as.integer))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
   year semester university_career unique_number
  <int>    <int>             <int>         <int>
1  2010        2               168            56
2  2014        1               152            13
3  2018        2                 8             6
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stringr::str_match()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- c(20102168056, 20102168356)

str_match(data, '^(\\d{4})(\\d{1})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})') %>%
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    set_names(c('value', 'year', 'semester', 'university_career', 'unique_number'))
#>         value year semester university_career unique_number
#> 1 20102168056 2010        2               168           056
#> 2 20102168356 2010        2               168           356
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substr()` function if you first make the number into a character with `as.character()`.

```r
test <- '20102168056'
data <- list()

data$year <- substr(test, 1, 4)
data$semester <- substr(test, 5, 5)
data$uni_career <- substr(test, 6, 8)
data$unique_num <- substr(test, 9, 11)

print(data)
#> $year
#> [1] "2010"
#> 
#> $semester
#> [1] "2"
#> 
#> $uni_career
#> [1] "168"
#> 
#> $unique_num
#> [1] "056"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>